# React Navigation: styling TabNavigator text

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-navigation

I am using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) in a create-react-native-app.

I am using the `TabNavigator` component like this (iPhone SE):

[image]

The `TabNavigator` is the dark blue strip with 'Job #1', 'Chat', Files', 'Details.

I want to customise the text of these items. I want non-uppercase text (which as far as I know is impossible to achieve with React Native Stylesheet), and to apply a fix for the 'Details' item which is wrapping onto two lines.

I have looked through the React Navigation API at TabNavigator but have not been able to find the answer.

How can I style these items?

Comment: Did you try usin `labelStyle` prop?

Comment: @bennygenel If I use `labelStyle`, how can I use CSS to control the casing of the text?

Comment: You can try using [`text-transform`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) property

Comment: @bennygenel that's not possible https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2088

Answer (score 24):

You can fix the non-uppercase issue with javascript:

```
navigationOptions: {
  tabBarLabel: 'Job #1'.toLowerCase(),
},
```

Or use the `tabBarOptions` property `upperCaseLabel`:

```
tabBarOptions: {
  upperCaseLabel: false,
}
```

To avoid the wrapping text I'm suggesting you reduce the font size of the labels:

```
tabBarOptions: {
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 10,
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
  },
}
```

Finally, it has to look something like this:

```
TabNavigator({
    ...
    filesTab: {
      screen: filesTabComponent,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Files'.toLowerCase(),
      },
    },
    ...
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
        upperCaseLabel: false,
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 18):

Simply do this for new version of react native

```
<Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarActiveTintColor: "#f5610a",
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: "#555",
      tabBarLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 10,
      },
    })}
  >
```

as you see in aboove line of code....just put following

```
tabBarLabelStyle: {
  fontSize: 10,
},
```

Inside

```
 screenOptions={({ route }) => ({  })}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
<Tab.Navigator 
  tabBarOptions={{
    labelStyle: { textTransform: "none", },
      style: {
        /* ** */
      },
}}>

  <Tab.Screen name="Screen 1" component={Screen1} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Screen 2" component={Screen2} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26311094)

Comment: @double-beep  style prop applies style for the whole tab screen navigation container while labelStyle applies style to the text label.

Answer (score 3):

To remove text wrapping you can do as below

```
tabBarOptions: {
    tabStyle: {
        width: 'auto'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import Followers from './Followers ';
import Following from './Following';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import CustomStatusBar from '../../../Components/CustomStatusBar';
import { COLORS } from '../../../Components/Colors';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const name = 'jklhdsjkhka';

export default function FolloweList() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <CustomStatusBar />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            tabBarActiveTintColor: '#00a3ff',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#F3B1CD',
            tabBarLabelStyle: { textAlign: 'center' },
            tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
              borderBottomColor: '#C2D5A8',
              borderBottomWidth: 2,
            },
            tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: COLORS.White },

            tabBarLabelStyle: {
              textTransform: 'none',
            },
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Followers} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Following} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There is property in tabbar

```
tabBarOptions:{ upperCaseLabel: false} //accept boolean default is true
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabbaroptions-for-tabbartop-default-tab-bar-on-android

Answer (score 1):

The API has changed, most other answers do not work anymore. This works:

```
<Tab.Navigator screenOptions={() => ({
  tabBarLabelStyle: styles.dashboard.tabBarLabelStyle
})}>
```

styles.dashboard.tabBarLabelStyle is the style object.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: "#50d3a7",
                inactiveTintColor: "gray",
                labelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 15,
                },
            }}
        >
```

refer:- [use referance](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-tab-navigator/issues/21#issuecomment-708283106)